# Open view controller when receiving remote Push Notification

Tags: objective-c, ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm using storyboard , and I want to open always the same view when user receives remote push notifications, even the app is in background or opened. The view I need to present is four views after the initial view controller set in the storyboard. I read this posts:

[How can I show a modal view in response to a notification as a new window? (no parent vc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430860/how-can-i-show-a-modal-view-in-response-to-a-notification-as-a-new-window-no-p)

[Open a specific tab/view when user receives a push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734338/open-a-specific-tab-view-when-user-receives-a-push-notification)

So here is my code:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    notificacionViewController *menu = [navController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"notificacion"];

    // First item in array is bottom of stack, last item is top.
    navController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:menu,nil];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


}
```

But when I receive notification, the app crashes with this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[locationViewController setViewControllers:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x42ccd0'
```

locationViewController is the view controller set as initial in the storyboard.

Many thanks.

Comment: Suppose, "HomeViewController" is the initial view controller in Storyboard, and after clicking a button, now you are in "SecondViewController" by push method. Now, you are getting Push notification. Do you want to push "NotificationViewController" or present it modally?

Comment: Modally, so I'm not sure to understand your explanation, you suggest to push the stack until I get notificacionViewController? Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please try the following code:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    NotificationViewController *notificationViewController = [[NotificationViewController alloc] init];
    [navController.visibleViewController.navigationController pushViewController:notificationViewController];    
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. It gives me this error:  No visible @interface for 'UINavigationController' declares the selector 'pushViewController:' for line [navController.visibleViewController.navigationController pushViewController:notificationViewController];

Comment: Please try this. [navController.visibleViewController.navigationController pushViewController:notificationViewController animated:YES];

Answer (score 2):

My code differs a bit from the answers I have seen. The fact is that the only code that works form me, is the following:

```
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];

    IniciarSliderViewController *controller = (IniciarSliderViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"MenuSlider"];

   [navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

1.- Instantiate de navigationController. Usually the rootviewcontroller in the vast majority of the cases, but not in all

2.- Instantiate the storyboard. Usuarlly tagged as MainStoryboard

3.- Instantiate your specific view controller. You must adapt for your special case

4.- Push as you should do because you've set all you need

Comment: How would you do that in case if app is up and running and user is deep inside of the app?