# Open a view Controller when push notification is received or redirected into another view controllerr

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, push-notification

My problem is when i am redirecting to another view controller the data is not coming. so please help me..

AppDelegate.m

i have declare like this

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    {

    NSDictionary *segueDictionary = [userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"];

    NSString *segueName=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[segueDictionary valueForKey:@"vendor_data"]];


    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@" Offers"
                                                        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"]]
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }

    else if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateInactive || [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateBackground)
    {





    MessageViewController * referObject = [[MessageViewController alloc]init];
    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:referObject animated:YES];

  UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    [navController.visibleViewController.navigationController pushViewController:referObject animated:YES];


    }

    }
```

`UIApplicationStateInactive` the app is just open and it is not 
redirect to `MessageViewController` and `UIApplicationStateBackground` the app is redirect to `MessageViewController`

I want to access the MessageViewController &
here MessageViewController is a Xib

Please help me....

Thanks

Comment: your method is called or not

Comment: What you meant by navController.visibleViewController.navigationController? is navController is enough?

Comment: it is directing but displaying nothing and i am new to iOS

Comment: @Johnykutty i have followed this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416745/open-view-controller-when-receiving-remote-push-notification   because i am new to iOS

Comment: this is the old methods , now most of the method are changed search the updated thing in googlre

Comment: are you using Storyboards ?

Comment: @JadFeitrouni i am using storyboards

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 8.x use

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(nullable NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler {
}
```

For iOS 9+ use

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(nullable NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo withResponseInfo:(NSDictionary *)responseInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler {
}
```

Comment: does this methods get called? nor not getting called?

Comment: this method is not called

Comment: you are testing on device or simulator?

Comment: testing in iphone only

Comment: you getting notification when the app is in background/suspended?