# react native PushNotificationIOS navigate on press to specific page

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a question I build my react native app and made the push notification work with all the notification, but i have one problem
I want my app to navigate to a specific page according to the notification received, is such a thing possible because when I tried my App Always went to the default page of the app.
on android i manged to make this work when the app is opened but when it is closed it crash's

Comment: Please follow this link:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416745/open-view-controller-when-receiving-remote-push-notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416745/open-view-controller-when-receiving-remote-push-notification)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Especially ios platform?